# MongoDB Aggregation: Unable to reference fields using $cond

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm performing an aggregation on a MongoDB collection. The steps preceeding the topical `$cond` are not important, so I'll redact them for brevity:

```
db.mycoll.aggregate([
  { $match: ... },
  { $project: ... },
  { /* this is the problem step */ }
])
```

The documents that are being generated by step 2, `$project`, are shaped like this:

```
{
  "blueTeam": true,
  "redTeam": false,
  "winner": true
}
```

Now assuming I add an additional projection which utilizes `$cond` - I'm not permitted to address the fields from the projected document. Here's a naive example:

```
{
  $project: {
    blueTeam: "$blueTeam",
    winnerAsInteger: {
      $cond: [ { "$winner": true }, 1, 0 ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Expectation**: The pipeline emits documents in which winning documents have field `winnerAsInteger` equal to 1, otherwise 0.

**Reality**: This pipeline step produces an error.

In Node's MongoDB client, the error is as follows:

> (node:34380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$winner'

In MongoDB Compass's aggregation GUI, the error is:

> Field must not begin with '$' or '.', field path was: $winner

This seems to directly contradict [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) regarding this, which references document fields with the `$` syntax.

I'm on MongoDB 4.0.5, for what it's worth.

Comment: Try  `{$eq:[ "$winner", true ]}` instead of  `{ "$winner": true }`

Comment: @Veeram Yes, that worked. If you want to make that an answer so I can give it credit.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`{$eq:[ "$winner", true ]} instead of { "$winner": true }`

Courtesy of @s7vr in comments, just added it here so that people don't think it's an unanswered question!